# To what extent should Stack Overflow Documentation cite its sources?

Tags: discussion, documentation

I've seen a lot of documentation with very authoritative examples. However, these don't cite any sources, leading to some question about their accuracy. In Java for instance, we have:

- [Coding Standards](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/java/1326/coding-standards)- Are these Oracle official standards or just ones that some SO user made up?
- [Garbage Collection](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/java/1009/garbage-collection#t=201607211935547800142)- There are statements about intentions of Java designers and the underlying processes including OS-level integration. How do I know these are accurate?

Also, we have some topics like [Optional](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/java/152/optional#t=201607211943557249408) that appear to be based on the [Oracle tutorial for Optional](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/java8-optional-2175753.html) and of course [the Javadoc for Optional](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html). However, no example cites these as sources.

To what extent should we expect Stack Overflow Documentation to cite sources?

Comment: It's got a bit of a smell to it - not saying it's a good or a bad thing at this point that those topics exist on Docs, but it almost doesn't feel like that's what Docs was meant for.

Comment: "To what extent should we expect Stack Overflow Documentation to cite sources?" All sources have to be cited unless they run under a license that does not require it. It's surely wrong to only cite half of the sources (or any other fraction).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First off, something everyone should already know but it's important so I'll lead with it anyways: plagiarism is wrong. If a bit of something from elsewhere is used in Docs, giving a citation is good manners and the right thing to do.

With that out of the way, hopefully we don't see this coming up very often. The purpose of Documentation on SO is **not** to be a place for people to copy-paste the official (or, for that matter, unofficial) documentation already being provided by Microsoft, Oracle, Google, Mozilla, &c. We're trying to build a different kind of resource.

Traditional documentation was written from a product perspective: some developer or team somewhere works hard, writes up a method or library or other thing, and then needs to explain it. Docs here will hopefully be written from a need-based perspective: you need to flux a widget, but the official documentation for `ThirdPartyLib.fluxWidgetHelper(Widget w, Int otherArg, Sprocket s) throws OneException, AnotherException, AllTheExceptions` just says

> takes Widget w and fluxes it

so you put up a request here. Then people who remember how rough it was learning how to flux widgets (maybe they had to ask on SO a few years ago?) but totally grok it now can write up something better.

How, then, will we ensure that the examples on Docs are good? The same way we "ensure" that Q&A answers are good: community voting and editing. If anything, I suspect editing will play an even bigger role here than it does with Q&A.

Comment: So does that mean we want to remove 3rd party content, rather than citing it and quoting it when we detect plagiarism? [I have a related question about this.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/330467/when-should-i-edit-plagiarism-to-cite-the-source-flag-or-remove)