# Documentation should include reference to official API document/specification

Tags: feature-request, documentation

Especially for parameters section. Example [CSS - Selectors](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/css/611/selectors#t=201607221138022802513)

Should there be a line in the suggestion box that encourage contributors to put in the official API document or specification links? That would be very helpful.

Comment: Absolutely, especially for these web stuff, there has been a large community effort in the past that places like MDN and webplatform.org contain current and correct content. Attempting to duplicate that here would be a terrible idea. If anything, we should focus on the *practical* side and provide examples using technology that’s documented elsewhere.

Comment: See also [Creating a topic which already has good official documentation - Meta Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328569/creating-a-topic-which-already-has-good-official-documentation).

Comment: See also [To what extent should Stack Overflow Documentation cite its sources?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/328713)